# ng-file-upload Resumable Upload Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I can't see any demo of a complete file upload with this plugin: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

That has a pause/resume/cancel feature? Also if possible not to trigger the submit function? I just want to "fileForm" form be submitted in the server. and not the "userForm"

I have this kind of setup

```
<form id="userForm" name="userForm>
....

<form id="fileForm" name="userForm">
</form>

</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks us for example code. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: There are plenty of example and a DEMO link at the top of the document.